# Call Parameterize iSeries Stored Procedure from .NET C#

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, odbc, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have a stored procedure created on the AS400 that takes in 2 parameters and returns either `000` if found or `001` if not found. I don't think I have the correct syntax for the `CommandText`. The following passes ?0 and 00 to the AS400. When I watch `CommandText` at the prepared statement it still shows `?` and `?`. Not sure if it normally fills it in.

I can hardcode the parameters "CALL DKDEXE.DKSLICCHK1 ('AAAAAA1','*43 spaces*')" and the AS400 gets the correct data and returns a valid 001 but I can not get that 001 back to my program. I'm out of ideas as to how to call the store procedure and get the return code. What is wrong with my code?

```
using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver=Client Access ODBC Driver (32-bit);System=X;Uid=U;Pwd=P"))
{
    cn.Open();

    using (OdbcCommand cm = cn.CreateCommand())
    { 
        cm.CommandText = "CALL DKDEXE.DKSLICCHK1 ('?','?')";
        cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cm.Parameters.Add("P1", OdbcType.Char).Value = "AAAAAAA1";
        cm.Parameters["P1"].Size = 8;
        cm.Parameters["P1"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        cm.Parameters.Add("P2", OdbcType.Char);
        cm.Parameters["P2"].Size = 43;
        cm.Parameters["P2"].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;

        cm.Prepare();
        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();

        string result = cm.Parameters["P2"].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Code on the AS400

```
    PROCEDURE DIVISION USING CALL-PARMS
                     CALL-PARMS1

    1000-MAIN.

        PERFORM 9999-PGM-INZ
        PERFORM 9999-PGM-EXIT

        GOBACK

        CONTINUE.

    9999-PGM-INZ.

        SET GOOD-RTN-CD TO TRUE
        MOVE SPACES TO RTN-MSG-1

        CALL 'SETLIB' USING
           OBJ-LIB
           DB-LIB
        END-CALL

        DISPLAY  CODE
        DISPLAY  NUMBER
        SET PGM-STR-PRG-MSG TO TRUE
        PERFORM 9999-SND-PRG-MSG
        CONTINUE.

    9999-SND-ON-OFF-MSG.
          EVALUATE TRUE
             WHEN CHK
                SET CHK1   TO TRUE
          END-EVALUATE
          EVALUATE TRUE
             WHEN GOOD-RTN-CD
                SET GOOD-RTN-TXT TO TRUE
             WHEN OTHER
                SET BAD-RTN-TXT TO TRUE
          END-EVALUATE
       STRING
           NUMBER        OF CALL-PARMS
           LS-RTN-CD
           RTN-MSG-1
           REQ-TYP-TXT
           REQ-RESULT-TXT
             DELIMITED BY SIZE
                INTO SND-ERR-MSG-SUB-DTA
        END-STRING
        PERFORM 9999-SND-ERR-MSG
        CONTINUE.
   9999-SND-PRG-MSG.
       SET LOG-MSG TO TRUE
       SET LOG-IN-PRG-MSG-ID TO TRUE
          STRING
             THIS-PROGRAM-NAME
             CUR-PRG-MSG
             DELIMITED BY SIZE
                INTO SND-ERR-MSG-SUB-DTA
          END-STRING
          PERFORM 9999-SND-ERR-MSG
       CONTINUE.


    9999-PGM-EXIT.
        PERFORM 9999-SND-ON-OFF-MSG
        SET PGM-END-PRG-MSG TO TRUE
        PERFORM 9999-SND-PRG-MSG
        CONTINUE.
```

Comment: I also tried {CALL DKDEXE.DKSLICCHK1 (?,?)} but I get an error 
ERROR [42S02] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0204 - DKSLI in DKDEXE type *N not found.

Comment: I'm not clear what result you're getting from which procedure.  What is the difference between DKSLI and DKSLICCHK1?  Why would you change the name? As long as you're checking into the exact name of the procedure you need to call, check to see that the parameters are CHAR.  They might be VARCHAR.  A mis-match would result in a 'not found' message.

Comment: The `SQL0204` almost certainly indicates a _signature mismatch_. Please provide the parameter declarations from the stored proc for us to look at.

Comment: Sorry I had a typo. I am calling DKDEXE.DKSLICCHK1 (?,?). I'm able to hardcode the parameters in but am lost on how to retrieve the value of the  return from the AS400. I will try and see if I can get the stored procedure code.

Comment: Updated with the AS400 code. Not sure if that is a stored procedure though.

Comment: It's only a part of the code, and it doesn't show the parameter definitions. It's code from the executable external program. Since it's a program, it can be declared as an 'external' stored proc; but we'd also need to see how the stored proc definition declares the parms in addition to how the program defines them.

Comment: Would be nice to know which version you have on IBM i and which version you have on the client side.